# Generated Interop Assembly from a C++ COM dll gives build reference error

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

I am trying to migrate my 32 bit application to x64bit, in my application I have a C++ COM dll
which I have build in x64 configuration. I am generating the Interop Assembly of the COM C++ dll using the command

```
        TLBIMP faacom.dll /out:Interop.FAACOMLib.dll
```

I have another C# project (Configuration - Any CPU) in which I am adding a reference of the above Interop dll.
But when I try to build my C# project it gives build error even when it is pointing to the correct path:

**Error 1    The type or namespace name 'FAACOMLib' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

But when I use the same Interop dll in my C# project which was generated from the 32bit compiled version of my C++ COM dll I do not get any build error.

I have tried generating the interop dll using x64 TLBIMP.exe but does not works.

Any Suggestions. Please Help...!!!

Thanks in Advance

Comment: "but does not works" is not an appropriate problem description.  You have to be more explicit about what is going wrong, nobody can see your C++ code.  Right-click the added reference and choose "View in Object Browser" so see what the namespace name looks like.

Comment: thanks for pointing me out to check the object browser. In the newly generated interop dll the namespace was Interop.FAACOMLib whereas in earlier 32 version it was FAACOMLib. I made the necessary changes in my code wherever required to Interop.FAACOMLib and it worked.             But I still wonder why the assembly name changed in new interop assembly as I did not made any change to my COM dll apart from target platform change from x86 to x64.                                  Anyway the problem is resolved...Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Apparently when you change the name of the DLL in the out-parameter of tlbimp, it changes the namespace as well for some reason. You can manually change the namespace with the namespace parameter. The command below should work I think.

```
TLBIMP faacom.dll /out:Interop.FAACOMLib.dll /namespace:FAACOMLib
```